# IP address showing on my web server together with the domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, vestacp

Recently I installed VESTACP and nginx, added domain name and everything is fine, I can access my website with domain but also when I type an IP address from server (http://11.11.11.11) I can access my website so is there any solution to avoid showing my ip address ?

Thank you guys

This is my nginx conf file:

```
    listen   11.11.3.171:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://11.11.3.171:8080;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://11.11.3.171:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

    include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.example.com.conf*;
}
```

Apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost 11.11.3.171:8080>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/example.com/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/example.com/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/example.com/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/example.com/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/apache2.example.com.conf*

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is just a protocol to resolve (domain-)names to their IP adresses, you can not really *hide* your adresse.

But you can use nginx to answer to requests using the appropriate name only.

In your nginx.conf (or sites- config) check fot the `listen`and `server_name`directive:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yourserver.com www.yourserver.com;
    ...
}
```

In the Nginx configuration file, you are allowed to have multiple server "{}" blocks. Incoming requests are matched against the `server_name` directive - in a top to down fashion.

In the case of multiple server blocks, if the request is for a non-existent domain, then it will always be handled by the *first* server block.

If you want to **block** requests coming from any other (aka 'not catched by existing block') adresses, just add the following server block to catch them:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

Setting `server_name` to `_` means 'default' or "[match all](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)". The response code `444`, returns as "NO RESPONSE", a special [nginx non-standard](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) that closes the connection immediately.

Comment: Hi, Bjoster, can you please check my updated question now, I have added the conf files for the nginix and apache. Thank you

Comment: Updated answer.